# Retrieve pinterest pin comments through the API

Tags: api, comments, pinterest, pins

I am using the v1 API ( https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/{PIN_ID}/ ... ) but there is no documentation on how to retrieve comments for certain pin.

So how do you do that?

Comment: I'm also facing same issue. Were you able to find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot currently retrieve comments for a Pin via the public API. You can only retrieve the comment count.

All available fields are listed at https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/pins/.